# How would you model in django a hierarchy of objects where one type might has itself as a child?

Tags: django, django-models

I would like to model the following hierarchy in Django, but don't really know how to approach the Opportunity relationships to other Opportunities and/or Solutions.

```
Outcome
|- Opportunity 1
|  |- Opportunity 1.1
|  |  |- Solution 1
|  |  |- Solution 2
|  |- Opportunity 1.2
|    |- Solution 3
|    |- Solution 4
|- Opportunity 2
   |- Solution 5
   |- Solution 6
```

- Each outcome has many Opportunities.
- Each Solution belongs to an Opportunity.
- Opportunities might either have many Opportunities or many Solutions, but not both.
- Sub-opportunities can not have more Opportunities, just Solutions.

Comment: Have you tried django-mptt? I haven't used it myself but it is meant for tree data structures and it looks like you could do this with it.

Answer (score 0):

Following upon @marc-compte's recommendation above, [django-polymorphic-tree](https://github.com/django-polymorphic/django-polymorphic-tree) provides both the tree functionality and the polymorphic aspect required here.